# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed

Tags: java, selenium

I have opened 2 tabs and closed the main tab then again I want to open another tab to do some operations at that time I am getting above error

1.My scripts will going to do the some operations in main tab
2.Then it will going to open new tab
3.Then it will switch back to main tab and it will close that
4.After that I want to open another new tab with same url I have used in main tab at that time I am getting the above error in selenium using java

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: the error suggests that the driver is in nomansland.  (The window/tab the driver is active in has been closed)

Comment: How to make the 2 tabs as active tabs?